# Reference problem with Microsoft Charts in ASP.Net Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, charts, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to migrate a C# .net framework MVC API to a .net Core 3 MVC API project that generates PNG charts with `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualisation.Charting.Chart`

I use [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization/) and everything looks fine except that the SaveImage method requires a reference to System.Windows.Forms.Control class, which is not part of my project, and as the project is a .net Core Web API project, this is impossible to reference it.

```
Chart chart = new Chart
{
    BackColor = Color.Transparent,
    Size = new Size(800, 800)
};
ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea() { BackColor = chart.BackColor };
chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

// Building of chart here

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png); // This method does not compile because it requires System.Windows.Forms.Control
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

I have this error:

> Error CS0012 The type 'Control' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

My project is `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` and therefore it's impossible to reference the `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms` package.

Is there workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. Simply by adding the following group into the .csproj file and now it compiles:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: And won't work on other platforms. This is probably the slowest way to generate graphs too - not only is this a *desktop* library, it can only generate full images, unlike the SVG graphics used by web sites. Your code doesn't dispose the chart classes which results in a GDI leak too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos indeed, but in this case I just have to migrate to .net Core an existing API running under IIS, so this is not a problem for now.